# Minecraft offline data

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

If you are playing offline in Minecraft, and a friend joins your world is it still offline? in other words, will it use any data if a friend joins?

Comment: ...how can a friend join your world if you're offline? Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'offline' you mean 'not on Wi-Fi' and by 'data' you mean 'mobile phone data' then I would assume that it is infact, using data.

Comment: yes, I did mean the things in your answer. Thank you so much.